# In Maven, how to push specific files to a specific location in AWS S3?

Tags: maven, amazon-s3, maven-plugin

I want to push some documentation to AWS S3 as part of a Maven build (`mvn deploy`).

I already use the Kuali S3 Wagon to push the code packages. Unfortunately, this is not helpful for documentation, as everything gets bundled into a `jar`. I need the documentation files to be uploaded individually so they can be directly served as a static website out of S3.

Can this be done without writing my own plug-in?

Answer (score 1):

here's a custom plugin that does what you need, if you have all the static files in a directory the following example shows how this plugin does the job.

Example: Recursively upload a folder

```
<build>
  ...

  <plugins>
    ...

    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>s3-upload-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <bucketName>my-s3-bucket</bucketName>
        <source>dir</source>
        <destination>remote-dir</destination>
        <recursive>true</recursive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Example: run the plugin

```
mvn com.bazaarvoice.maven.plugins:s3-upload-maven-plugin:1.2:s3-upload
```

(https://github.com/moacyrricardo/s3-upload-maven-plugin)